# How can I set the filename of the created .deb file when building my Electron.NET application for Linux?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron.net

This is my electron.manifest.json

```
{
    "executable": "MyApplication.UI",
    "splashscreen": {
        "imageFile": "/wwwroot/assets/Animation.svg"
    },
    "author": "MyCompany",
    "environment": "Production",
    "singleInstance": false,
    "build": {
        "appId": "com.mycompany.myapplication",
        "productName": "MyApplication",
        "copyright": "Copyright @ 2022",
        "buildVersion": "2022.1.0",
        "compression": "maximum",
        "fileAssociations": [
            {
                "ext": "sdg",
                "name": "MyApplication File",
                "role": "Editor"
            }
        ],
        "publish": {
            "provider": "generic",
            "url": "https://mydomain.io/Installer/MyApplication/",
            "channel": "latest"
        },
        "nsis": {
            "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
            "oneClick": false,
            "perMachine": true,
            "installerIcon": "bin/Assets/icon.ico",
            "uninstallerIcon": "bin/Assets/icon.ico",
            "installerHeaderIcon": "bin/Assets/icon.ico",
            "menuCategory": true
        },
        "win": {
            "target": [
                "nsis"
            ],
            "icon": "Assets/icon.ico"
        },
        "linux": {
            "target": "deb",
            "maintainer": "MyCompany",
            "vendor": "MyCompany",
            "synopsis": "MyApplication",
            "executableName": "MyApplication",
            "description": "Doing some magic.",
            "category": "Development",
            "icon": "./../../Assets/Icons/32x32.png"
        },
        "directories": {
            "output": "../../../bin/Installer",
            "buildResources": "Assets"
        },
        "extraResources": [
            {
                "from": "./bin",
                "to": "bin",
                "filter": [
                    "**/*"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "files": [
            {
                "from": "./ElectronHostHook/node_modules",
                "to": "ElectronHostHook/node_modules",
                "filter": [
                    "**/*"
                ]
            },
            "**/*"
        ]
    }
}
```

The created .deb file when building for linux is called `electron-net_{version}.deb`. That wouldn't be a problem but when executed, the application name `electron-net` is shown.

[image]

How can I change that? I checked the documentation (here https://www.electron.build/configuration/linux) already but I dont see any more options in my config?

I am using ElectronNET.CLI Version 15.5.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.4, .NET Version 5.0.406

Comment: Hey is there a way to get the icon for the installer in the above image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `artifactName` property under build for your file name and the `name` property under at root for the name that is displayed

```
{
  "name" : "MyApplication",
  "executable" : "MyApplication",
  "build": {
    "artifactName": "my-application.${ext}",  
  }
}
```

Comment: @marco-siffert https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration.html

something of note here, there is also a productName property that can be used for a free form name field.  the name property has restrictions on content.  see the linked documentation.